# Issue Deploying Mule 3.6.0 CE Application on IBM WebSphere 8.5.5

Tags: web-services, cxf, mule, websphere-8, ibm-was

We have developed a web service using mule CXF node and it works fine when runinng the service from Anypoint Studio or on Apache tomcat but when we deploy the service on IBM WebSphere we got the below exception:

```
[5/21/15 15:39:02:931 EEST] 000000be SystemErr     R com.ibm.ws.exception.RuntimeWarning: com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.exception.WebAppNotLoadedException: Failed to load webapp: Failed to load webapp: javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer: Provider org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer not a subtype
[5/21/15 15:39:02:931 EEST] 000000be SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.install(WebContainerImpl.java:432)
[5/21/15 15:39:02:931 EEST] 000000be SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.start(WebContainerImpl.java:718)
[5/21/15 15:39:02:931 EEST] 000000be SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1177)
[5/21/15 15:39:02:931 EEST] 000000be SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.fireDeployedObjectStart(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1370)
[5/21/15 15:39:02:931 EEST] 000000be SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.start(DeployedModuleImpl.java:639)
[5/21/15 15:39:02:931 EEST] 000000be SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.start(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:968)
[5/21/15 15:39:02:931 EEST] 000000be SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:776)
[5/21/15 15:39:02:931 EEST] 000000be SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplicationDynamically(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1379)
[5/21/15 15:39:02:931 EEST] 000000be SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2189)
[5/21/15 15:39:02:931 EEST] 000000be SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:435)
[5/21/15 15:39:02:931 EEST] 000000be SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitImpl.start(CompositionUnitImpl.java:123)
[5/21/15 15:39:02:931 EEST] 000000be SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:378)
[5/21/15 15:39:02:931 EEST] 000000be SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.access$500(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:126)
[5/21/15 15:39:02:931 EEST] 000000be SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl$1.run(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:653)
[5/21/15 15:39:02:931 EEST] 000000be SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAs(ContextManagerImpl.java:5477)
[5/21/15 15:39:02:931 EEST] 000000be SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAsSystem(ContextManagerImpl.java:5603)
[5/21/15 15:39:02:931 EEST] 000000be SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.security.core.SecurityContext.runAsSystem(SecurityContext.java:255)
[5/21/15 15:39:02:931 EEST] 000000be SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.startCompositionUnit(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:667)
[5/21/15 15:39:02:931 EEST] 000000be SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.startCompositionUnit(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:611)
[5/21/15 15:39:02:931 EEST] 000000be SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1269)
[5/21/15 15:39:02:931 EEST] 000000be SystemErr     R    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[5/21/15 15:39:02:931 EEST] 000000be SystemErr     R    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:95)
[5/21/15 15:39:02:931 EEST] 000000be SystemErr     R    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:56)
[5/21/15 15:39:02:931 EEST] 000000be SystemErr     R    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:620)
[5/21/15 15:39:02:931 EEST] 000000be SystemErr     R    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:88)
[5/21/15 15:39:02:931 EEST] 000000be SystemErr     R    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor35.invoke(Unknown Source)
[5/21/15 15:39:02:931 EEST] 000000be SystemErr     R    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:56)
[5/21/15 15:39:02:931 EEST] 000000be SystemErr     R    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:620)
[5/21/15 15:39:02:931 EEST] 000000be SystemErr     R    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:292)
[5/21/15 15:39:02:931 EEST] 000000be SystemErr     R    at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean$4.run(RequiredModelMBean.java:1261)
[5/21/15 15:39:02:931 EEST] 000000be SystemErr     R    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:311)
[5/21/15 15:39:02:931 EEST] 000000be SystemErr     R    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:88)
[5/21/15 15:39:02:931 EEST] 000000be SystemErr     R    at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invokeMethod(RequiredModelMBean.java:1255)
[5/21/15 15:39:02:931 EEST] 000000be SystemErr     R    at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invoke(RequiredModelMBean.java:1093)
[5/21/15 15:39:02:931 EEST] 000000be SystemErr     R    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:832)
[5/21/15 15:39:02:931 EEST] 000000be SystemErr     R    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:814)
[5/21/15 15:39:02:931 EEST] 000000be SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl$1.run(AdminServiceImpl.java:1335)
[5/21/15 15:39:02:931 EEST] 000000be SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.security.util.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:118)
[5/21/15 15:39:02:931 EEST] 000000be SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl.invoke(AdminServiceImpl.java:1228)
[5/21/15 15:39:02:931 EEST] 000000be SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.management.commands.AdminServiceCommands$InvokeCmd.execute(AdminServiceCommands.java:251)
[5/21/15 15:39:02:931 EEST] 000000be SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.console.core.mbean.MBeanHelper.invoke(MBeanHelper.java:241)
[5/21/15 15:39:02:931 EEST] 000000be SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.console.appdeployment.ApplicationDeploymentCollectionAction.execute(ApplicationDeploymentCollectionAction.java:583)
[5/21/15 15:39:02:931 EEST] 000000be SystemErr     R    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(Unknown Source)
[5/21/15 15:39:02:931 EEST] 000000be SystemErr     R    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(Unknown Source)
[5/21/15 15:39:02:931 EEST] 000000be SystemErr     R    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(Unknown Source)
[5/21/15 15:39:02:931 EEST] 000000be SystemErr     R    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(Unknown Source)
[5/21/15 15:39:02:931 EEST] 000000be SystemErr     R    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:595)
[5/21/15 15:39:02:931 EEST] 000000be SystemErr     R    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
[5/21/15 15:39:02:931 EEST] 000000be SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1230)
[5/21/15 15:39:02:931 EEST] 000000be SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:779)
[5/21/15 15:39:02:931 EEST] 000000be SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:478)
[5/21/15 15:39:02:931 EEST] 000000be SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
[5/21/15 15:39:02:931 EEST] 000000be SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:136)
[5/21/15 15:39:02:931 EEST] 000000be SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:79)
[5/21/15 15:39:02:931 EEST] 000000be SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:967)
[5/21/15 15:39:02:931 EEST] 000000be SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1107)
[5/21/15 15:39:02:931 EEST] 000000be SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.dispatch(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:1385)
[5/21/15 15:39:02:931 EEST] 000000be SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.forward(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:194)
[5/21/15 15:39:02:931 EEST] 000000be SystemErr     R    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.doForward(Unknown Source)
[5/21/15 15:39:02:931 EEST] 000000be SystemErr     R    at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor.doForward(Unknown Source)
[5/21/15 15:39:02:931 EEST] 000000be SystemErr     R    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processForwardConfig(Unknown Source)
[5/21/15 15:39:02:931 EEST] 000000be SystemErr     R    at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor.processForwardConfig(Unknown Source)
[5/21/15 15:39:02:931 EEST] 000000be SystemErr     R    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(Unknown Source)
[5/21/15 15:39:02:931 EEST] 000000be SystemErr     R    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(Unknown Source)
[5/21/15 15:39:02:931 EEST] 000000be SystemErr     R    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(Unknown Source)
[5/21/15 15:39:02:931 EEST] 000000be SystemErr     R    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:595)
[5/21/15 15:39:02:931 EEST] 000000be SystemErr     R    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
[5/21/15 15:39:02:931 EEST] 000000be SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1230)
[5/21/15 15:39:02:931 EEST] 000000be SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:779)
[5/21/15 15:39:02:931 EEST] 000000be SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:478)
[5/21/15 15:39:02:931 EEST] 000000be SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
[5/21/15 15:39:02:931 EEST] 000000be SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:136)
[5/21/15 15:39:02:931 EEST] 000000be SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:97)
[5/21/15 15:39:02:931 EEST] 000000be SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.console.core.servlet.WSCUrlFilter.setUpCommandAssistance(WSCUrlFilter.java:964)
[5/21/15 15:39:02:931 EEST] 000000be SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.console.core.servlet.WSCUrlFilter.continueStoringTaskState(WSCUrlFilter.java:511)
[5/21/15 15:39:02:931 EEST] 000000be SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.console.core.servlet.WSCUrlFilter.doFilter(WSCUrlFilter.java:332)
[5/21/15 15:39:02:931 EEST] 000000be SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
[5/21/15 15:39:02:931 EEST] 000000be SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
[5/21/15 15:39:02:931 EEST] 000000be SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:967)
[5/21/15 15:39:02:931 EEST] 000000be SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1107)
[5/21/15 15:39:02:931 EEST] 000000be SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:87)
[5/21/15 15:39:02:931 EEST] 000000be SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:919)
[5/21/15 15:39:02:931 EEST] 000000be SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1662)
[5/21/15 15:39:02:931 EEST] 000000be SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:200)
[5/21/15 15:39:02:931 EEST] 000000be SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:463)
[5/21/15 15:39:02:931 EEST] 000000be SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:530)
[5/21/15 15:39:02:931 EEST] 000000be SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:316)
[5/21/15 15:39:02:931 EEST] 000000be SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:88)
[5/21/15 15:39:02:931 EEST] 000000be SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLReadServiceContext$SSLReadCompletedCallback.complete(SSLReadServiceContext.java:1818)
[5/21/15 15:39:02:931 EEST] 000000be SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
[5/21/15 15:39:02:931 EEST] 000000be SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
[5/21/15 15:39:02:931 EEST] 000000be SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
[5/21/15 15:39:02:931 EEST] 000000be SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
[5/21/15 15:39:02:931 EEST] 000000be SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
[5/21/15 15:39:02:931 EEST] 000000be SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
[5/21/15 15:39:02:931 EEST] 000000be SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
[5/21/15 15:39:02:931 EEST] 000000be SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1881)
```

Comment: Do you happen to package the Servlet API JAR in the WAR by accident?

Comment: @DavidDossot I'm using Maven to build the project which JAR do you mean?

Comment: The Servlet API has been packaged by many JARs so I can't tell you which one brings it to your classpath. Check what JAR(s) brings the `javax.servlet` package to your project.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for this issue which was as @DavidDosst pointed out a servlet jar included the the war file the jar name is geronimo-servlet_3.0_spec-1.0.jar and the issue was solved once i deleted this jar also a detailed description of the process of deploying CXF to WAS can be found at:

- http://cxf.apache.org/docs/application-server-specific-configuration-guide.html#ApplicationServerSpecificConfigurationGuide-ForWebSphere6.1.0.29+,V7andV8
- http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/dw/wes/1001_thaker/1001_thaker.pdf